# Obtener datos de un LIST en java

Tags: java, spring

Estoy intentanto recorrer una lista con un for pero el problema es que de size() solo hay uno el cual es el que tiene varios datos y necesito obtener el id,nombre, fechainicio y fechafinal pero al hacer el `list.get(2)`  para obtener posicion 2 me da error ya que no existe por que solo hay 1 con todos los datos el cual me muestra el siguiente.

Sin hacer con el for solo imprimiendo la lista
`[{Id=1, Nombre=Aplicacion, FechaInicio=2020-09-27, FechaFinal=2020-10-23, IdUsDesarrolla=3, IdUsAsigna=1}]`

cuando lo hago con el for es asi:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < listterminar.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(listterminar.get(i));
                }

// resultado del for en un solo recorrido ya que el size es 1: {Id=1, Nombre=Aplicacion, FechaInicio=2020-09-27, FechaFinal=2020-10-23, IdUsDesarrolla=3, IdUsAsigna=1}
```

Los nombres con los que viene en esa lista es como están en la base de datos, no son objetos set ni get.

los cuales los obtengo asi:

`listfunciones = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("CALL Tr_listfunciones (?,?,?)",asigna, desarrolla, tipo);` y retorno la lista al controlador

Comment: linda en Java el primer elemento de un arreglo es la posición 0 no la 1 y la tercera posición es la 2 por lo que a size debes restarle 1 si haces get(2) accedes al tercer elemento no al segundo

Comment: @Japv, si lose que comienza desde 0 pero necesito obtener los campos que mencione y si le pongo que deseo la posicion 2 que seria la FechaInicio me da error por que la lista me esta diciendo que el size() da hasta 1 que tiene el valor de toda la cadena que puse

Comment: En [esta web](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) hay varios ejemplos. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al obtener la lista con `jdbcTemplate.queryForList` lo que obtienes es un  `List<Map<String, Object>>` por lo que puedes hacer algo asi:

```
       List<Map<String, Object>> listfunciones = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    
            for (Map row : listfunciones ) {
                    System.out.println(row.get("Id"));
                    //El resto de campos los cogerias con su nombre
            }
```

Comment: no los datos no estan en get ya que solo los obtuve de la siguiente manera ```   listgrupo = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("CALL listafunciones"); ``` los campos que se ven es como estan en la base de datos

Comment: Oye ese me sirvió super genial, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del .forEach de List para recorrer cada item de la lista y obtener un Map<String, Object> de cada item.

- Con jdbcTemplate.queryForList obtienes una Lista de Map<String, Object> `List<Map<String, Object>>` con esa lista puedes realizar algo así:

  ```
   List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);

   result.forEach(row -> {
       System.out.println(row.get("Id"));
       System.out.println(row.get("Nombre"));
       System.out.println(row.get("FechaInicio"));
       //....
   });
  ```